# What is the difference between Project's background and Project Significance?

Tags: writing

I need to write my project's significance.

I googled to find examples on project's significance, but I found article referring to project's background and significance as the same thing.

https://orsp.umich.edu/research-proposals-background-or-significance

Do I need to write a background about my project in the when asked to provide project's significance?

Comment: It's the difference between who you are and where you came from. Yes, the two answers are intertwined, but they focus on different aspects.

Comment: And where you can possibly go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **Background**: what (general) information should the panel know to properly judge the project. For example: What has been done before? How does your project relate to this previous work? If your project is about disease X, what is this disease exactly?
- **Significance** is another word for "importance" or "impact". Why is the project important, for example: How many people are affected by disease X, and what do you expect to achieve when the project is completed. Better knowledge about the disease mechanism? A cure? A better detection mechanism? The structure of a protein involved in the disease (how does it help if we know the structure)? What they want to know is: How important is your project and how does it help to make the world better?

There is indeed some overlap between the two, but the requirement to write a section about the significance indicates that they want it to be separated from the background, without overlap.